# How to run a deploy command on remote host from PyCharm?

Tags: django, deployment, pycharm

I am looking for a way to simplify remote deployment of a django application directly from PyCharm.

Even if deploying the files itself works just file with the remote host and upload, I was not able to find a way to run the additional commands on the server site (like manage.py syncdb).

I am looking for a fully automated solution, one that would work at single click (or command).

Comment: hey, did you find a solution for this? I mean is there a way to run/re-run the process on the remote host ? some thing like `nohup python run.py &`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about PyCharm so maybe you could do something from the IDE, but I think  you'll probably want to take a look at the fabric project  (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html)

It's a python deployment automation tool that's pretty great.

Here is one of my fabric script files.  Note that I make a lot of assumptions (This is my own that I use) that completely depend on how you want to set up your project, such as I use virtualenv, pip, and south as well as my own personal preference for how to deploy and where to deploy to.

You'll likely want to rework or simplify it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **File > Settings > Tools > External Tools** to run arbitrary external executable files. You may write a small command that connects over SSH and issues a [set of] command. Then the configured tool would be executable

For example, in my project based on [tornado](https://tornadoweb.org), I run the instances using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), which, according to [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422492/why-is-supervisor-not-recognizing-code-changes), cannot restart upon code change.

I ended up writing a small tool on [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), that connects via ssh and runs `supervisorctl restart`. The code is below:

```
import paramiko
from optparse import OptionParser


parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-s",
                  action="store",
                  dest="server",
                  help="server where to execute the command")
parser.add_option("-u",
                  action="store",
                  dest="username")
parser.add_option("-p",
                  action="store",
                  dest="password")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(hostname=options.server, port=22, username=options.username, password=options.password)
command = "supervisorctl reload"
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command(command)
for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line
client.close()
```

External Tool configuration in Pycharm:

- program: `<PYTHON_INTERPRETER>`
- parameters: `<PATH_TO_SCRIPT> -s <SERVERNAME> -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>`