# Why is Supervisor not recognizing code changes?

Tags: monitoring, supervisord

I'm using [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) to manage my node.js applicaton on an EC2 instance with git for deployment. Supervisor does a good job of making sure my application stays up, but whenever I push new server-side code to my remote server, it tends to not recognize those changes. I need to kill the supervisor process and restart it. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this standard behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is standard behaviour; supervisord does not detect changes in code. It only restarts processes if they themselves stop or die.

Just instruct supervisord to restart the application whenever you push changes. `supervisorctl restart programname` is fine, no need to kill and restart supervisord itself.

If the supervisord configuration changed, use `supervisorctl update`.

Comment: Thanks! Where does `supervisorctl` live? Do I need to set any configuration for it?

Comment: @user730569: same place as `supervisord`; see http://supervisord.org/introduction.html#supervisor-components

Comment: @user730569: Also a helpful part of the documentation: http://supervisord.org/running.html

Comment: When i run `supervisorctl update` I get an error: `error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py line: 567`

Comment: @user730569: We are stretching the SO Q&A format to it's limits now. Review the supervisord documentation, and compare that with how you configured supervisord. `supervisorctl` uses the same configuration as the daemon to figure out how to talk to it, but if the daemon isn't running then contacting it will fail, *or* it means `supervisorctl` isn't using the same configuration and is looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to add a `unix_http_server` part to the configuration.

Comment: is `supervisorctl restart programname` the same than doing `supervisorctl stop programname` and then `supervisorctl start programname` ?

Comment: @Tms91: [yes](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/supervisorctl.py#L955-L968)